# Internet Explorer Issues and Solutions

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've read so many articles about IE issues about css.
I am about to use this conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
```

But, where in the world can I get the "all-ie-only.css" ?
Or what is inside it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IE9 and 10 are largely free from issues requiring per-browser stylesheets. Furthermore conditional-comments are not supported by IE10. Do you have an actual problem where you need IE-only styles?

Comment: What's inside that css? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That CSS file will only exist if you create it. The point of IE Conditional comments is to execute code only in IE, while it's ignored by other browsers. You can also specify specific versions of IE to target with your conditional comments as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=VS.85).aspx).

For a simpler solution, consider the html tag classes as explained in [Paul Irish's blog post](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/), and then you can target specific versions of IE in your regular stylesheet by prepending your rules with the appropriate classes, e.g.:

```
.ie .component-name p {
  position: static;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant parts of Paul Irish's blog post in your answer to safeguard against it going dead, being blocked by firewall, etc.? That way, nobody needs to rely on the link to find your answer useful. Many thanks.